# Postgresql error when running rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I'm learning how to code by pulling a repository from an account. However, when I try to run `rails s` I get this error:

> PG::ConnectionBad - FATAL:  password authentication failed for user
>   "postgres" FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

I have a basically clean install of postgresql and I can't figure out what to do. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Check the database.yml file and see what password you have set.I think you din't setup the same password for the user postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh... It turns out that I've put in the wrong port number. It was only responding to the one I specified in database.yml. Port was 5432 and I changed it to 3000 and it worked.